# Don't run javascript function in PartialView

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I add a js file in masterpage. and use it in View.

```
<div class="control-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Computers, new { @class = "control-label" })
 <div id="computersEditorRows" style="clear: both; margin-right: 30px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);">
   @foreach (var item in Model.Computers)
    {
      Html.RenderPartial("_ComputersEditorRow", item);
    }

  </div>
  <a id="addItemcomputer" style="cursor: pointer;">AddItem</a>
 </div>
```

and js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#addItemcomputer").click(function () {
    $.get("/TechnicalOfficerService/AddComputerNewRow", function (data) {
        $("#computersEditorRows").append(data);

    }).fail(function (xhr, err) {
        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    });
 });
})
```

But when i use this in Partialview, don't call function. I use this html code in partial view, but don't call `$("#addItemcomputer").click`.

Partial View

```
@model PSYCO.Web.Sepid.ViewModels.ComputerViewModel
@using PSYCO.Web.Sepid.Helpers;
<div class="control-group">
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Computers"))
{
   <div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Computers, new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div id="computersEditorRows" style="clear: both; margin-right: 30px; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Computers)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_ComputersEditorRow", item);
            }

        </div>
        <a id="addItemcomputer" style="cursor: pointer;">Add Item</a>
    </div>
  <a class="removeItemNationality" style="cursor: pointer;">Delete</a>
   }
 </div>
```

**EDIT**

Add this section in partial view.

```
 @section Scripts
 {
  <script>
   $(document).on("click","#addItemcomputer",function () {
     alert('d');
     })
   </script>
 }
```

Comment: so what's the error. The scripts is not being called or /TechnicalOfficerService/AddComputerNewRow is 404

Comment: I use this in a view , it is work. but when i use this in Partial view, don't run function.

Comment: how do you use it in the partial view?

Comment: on browser right click and view source code can you see #addItemcomputer link in html, i think @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Computers")) has some problem and html in it do not get render

Comment: where you load js file??

Comment: Yes , I have `<a id="addItemcomputer " style="cursor: pointer;">Add Item</a>` in html source

Comment: Load in `BootstrapBundleConfig`. Add all script in `RegisterBundles`.

Comment: you can try delegated event as partial view renders dynamically so may be script is rendered before partial view thats why it is not able to find it in DOM :``$(document).on("click","#addItemcomputer",function () {``

Comment: I use this, but don't run function.

Comment: how you used can you show code?

Comment: are you sure jquery is included and no error on console

Comment: You cannot use sections in partial views.

Comment: try describe this  @section Scripts
 {
  <script>
   $(document).on("click","#addItemcomputer",function () {
     alert('d');
     })
   </script>
 } inside the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should add script in PartialView.

Use script link in Partial View.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SomeScript.js")"></script>
```

Or use script tag in Partial View.(cannot use sections in partial views)

```
<script>
$("#addItemcomputer").click(function () {
$.get("/TechnicalOfficerService/AddComputerNewRow", function (data) {
    $("#computersEditorRows").append(data);

}).fail(function (xhr, err) {
    alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
});
});
</script>
```