# Javascript does not run on PartialView

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using MVC4, with C# and Razor to make a simple Web Application.

In my Controller I have a method that returns a partial view that is shown to the user, in this case, a modal popup:

```
public ActionResult GetPackageDetails(int id)
{ 
    return PartialView("_EditPackageModal", new ModalEditPackage());
}
```

The partial view, which is a modal popup shows as predicted, but does not run any javascript:

```
@model SuperApp.Model.ModalEditPackage

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="editPackageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editPackages" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Package @Model.packageName</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div>
                    <label class="control-label">Package Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="package-name" placeholder="@Model.packageName">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript code that I wish to run on the partial view:

```
<script>
    $("input").click(function () {
        alert("hello world!");
    });
</script>
```

After reading this question:

- [Don't run javascript function in PartialView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177728/dont-run-javascript-function-in-partialview)

I realized that I **must** include the script in the partial view. To sum up:

1. The partial view is unable to run the JS code that is in my project.
2. The partial view only runs JS code that is directly specified in the partial view using the `<script>` tag

Now, in this example such is fine, but in the real world I have several scripts that work on the partial view, and they are considerably big. Furthermore, the client already downloaded them because they are being used in other views and I don't know how to tell the partial view where the scripts are located since I am using Bundles.

Is there a way to fix this without smashing the script directly into the partial view?

Comment: You can run your script from any view that contains the partial and it will work just fine, remember that views render server side, and js executes in the browser so by the time the view gets to the browser there is nothing to signify any part of it came from a partial view.. The question you link to is about the fact that  you can't have sections in partial views.

Comment: But their solution works for part of my problem - at least now the partial view is able to run JS, but not the way I want to. Is there any other solution I can use?

Comment: So you partial view is actually being loaded by ajax request correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728474/how-to-use-bootstrap-modal-to-edit-the-table-data-in-mvc/15728536#15728536

Comment: Can you explain what problem the linked question fixes, given that it is about using @section in a partial view, which you are not doing.

Comment: 1. The partial view is unable to run the JS code that is in my project.
2. The partial view only runs JS code that is directly specified in the partial view using the `<script>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give unique name to all your modals or html blocks. 
Make your js code like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#yourSpecifiedDomElement input','click',function(){
    alert("hello world!");
});
```

place all your javascript code to specified js files which included in bundles.